# What are the most useful plugins for Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Plugins and tools that work with Gmail to increase productivity.

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki? Usefulness is subjective.

Comment: This should be a wiki.

Comment: Please make any questions asking for a "list of X" community wiki when you post them. I converted this question.

Answer (score 5):

[Better Gmail 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6076/) encapsulates a number of helpful add-ons that I like. (Requires [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748), and, thus, Firefox.)

Currently:

- Add Row Highlights: Highlights the letter rows in the new Gmail when you hover over them with the mouse cursor.
- Attachment Icons: See what kind of attachment an email has in list view.
- Attachment Icons (Native): Same as attachment icons, but uses icon images native to your system.
- Bottom Post in Reply (Plain Text only): Inserts cursor after the quoted message in plain text replies automatically.
- Label Links: Lists labels in a folder-like hierarchy.
- Hide Buzz Count: Hides the unread count next to Buzz in Gmail.
- Hide Chat: Hides Gmail's Chat box in the sidebar.
- Hide Invites Box: Hides the Gmail invites box on the sidebar.
- Hide Labels in Message Row: Hides the labels that appear in a message row unless the user hovers over the message.
- Hide Spam Count: Hides Gmail's Spam message count.
- Inbox Count First: See unread message count first on Gmail tab title.
- Play Sound Notifications for New Mail: Plays an audible notification when you receive new email.
- Show Unread Message Count on Favicon: Shows the number of unread Gmail messages in the favicon in your Firefox tab.

Comment: BTW, Greasemonkey for Chrome is out. http://mashable.com/2010/02/01/google-chrome-greasemonkey-2/

Answer (score 4):

I am a huge fan of [Rapportive](http://rapportive.com), definitely worth checking out (free)

Rapportive integrates into your gmail and serves as a simple CRM.

Answer (score 3):

Google's own Gmail Labs features are a major benefit for me.

Comment: Among the dozen labs I have enabled, I particularly like "Canned Responses", "Don't forget Bob", "Got the wrong Bob?", and "Inserting images"

Answer (score 2):

From Gmail Labs:

**Undo Send** should be enabled by default !
Saves you for instance from the accidental tab-enter...

I also like the **Mark as Read Button**.

Comment: I LOVE LOVE LOVE "Undo Send" - and now you can change/extend the undo interval

Answer (score 1):

I like [GMail notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html), which lets you know you have new mail, even if you don't have a browser window (or a gmail tab) open.

Answer (score 0):

From Gmail Labs, the 2 I have enabled:

[Title Tweaks](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/new-in-labs-browser-title-bar-tweaks.html) - puts the # of new msgs in the title so you can see it when your browser window is minimized. e.g. "Inbox (3) - you@gmail.com"

[Inserting Images](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/new-in-labs-inserting-images.html) - allows direct embedding of images into the body of your email (not sure why this isn't part of the "core" app)

Answer (score 0):

If you send and receive a lot of documents by email, DokDok (dokdok.com) is pretty handy.

I'm the Founder, sorry for the shameless plug, couldn't resist such an open question.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Mail Checker Plus](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gffjhibehnempbkeheiccaincokdjbfe?hl=en) is an excellent extension to Chrome. It not only notifies you of new emails and shows the preview of the message but also allows to

- mark email as Read
- mark email as Spam
- Archive email
- Delete email

all that without opening the email itself.
I wish those features where added to the email notifier in Google Talk client